# Finding the smallest $k$ such that $10^k\equiv1\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $\gcd(10,k)=1$, the period of the repeating decimal of $1/n$ is equal to the smallest integer $k$ such that $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod n$

For example: $1/21 = 0,\overline{047619}$ and so $10^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{21}$

Is there an elementary proof for this? Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Combine the two observations: A) the future of the grade school algorithm for calculating $1/n$ depends only on the current remainder (mod $n$), B) if your remainder while calculating decimal $d_k$ is some $a_k$, then the remainder while calculating $d_{k+1}$ is $a_{k+1}\equiv 10a_k\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be the period of the repeating decimal for $1/n.$ Then $10^k(1/n)=a+1/n,$ where $a$ is an integer. This implies that $n\mid 10^k-1.$
Hope this helps.
P.S. $a$ is the integer formed by the repeating decimals. In your example, $a=47619.$

Answer (score 0):

As $21=3\cdot7,$

$\displaystyle10\equiv1\pmod3\implies $  [Multiplicative order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) ord$_3(10)=1$

Again, $\displaystyle10\equiv3\pmod7\implies 10^2\equiv3^2\equiv2,10^3\equiv3^3\equiv-1$

$\displaystyle\implies10^6\equiv1\implies $ord$_7(10)=6$

We can prove, ord$_pa=d_1,$ord$_qa=d_2\ $ord$_{\text{lcm}(p,q)}a=$lcm$(d_1,d_2)$

See also : [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)